# Как запустить Youtube трансляцию и вести ее?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

столкнулся с задачей. Мне нужен создать трансляцию и вести её через Java. Под словом "вести" подразумевается транслировать определенное видео.

Comment: используйте `selenium`

Comment: у вас веб-приложение? или десктоп?

Comment: у меня десктоп.